# I can't send an email with smtp

Tags: email, smtp, server, scada

I want to send an email with a software that I use called ("ScadaBR" it's for industriel supervision).

I use the name of the server that my company uses to send emails in the "SMTP host", with the port 25. but I have an error **"connection failed with the server"**

This is the error:

> Failed to send email titled "ScadaBR test email" to "FRWLT@bost.com".
>   Message: "Mail server connection failed; nested exception is
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp-eu.app.corp, port: 25; nested exception is:
>   java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10107:
>   connect"

The email destination is:FRWLT@bost.com

The server name is : smtp-eu.app.corp

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing smtp-eu.app.corp is a .corp address, it's an address in your Local Network? If so, is that server reachable from the webserver hosting the site?
Also some SMTP servers require an username and password or the IP address of the webserver (if it's on the same LAN) must be allowed to send mail from it's IP address through the SMTP server.
If it's an application running on your local computer, could you test with a programm like "putty" to connect to smtp-eu.app.corp on port 25 (choosing telnet as connection method) to see if you can connect to it
Could you provide more details on the situation (if this isn't the answer)?

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I can test the connection with the ( smtp-eu.app.corp) with the command "ping" from a terminal  and I got a answer so I can communicate with this machine, I tried also  to do the same thing with "putty" but the pytty terminal return nothing I don't know the meaning of that.
I agree with you that some SMTP servers require an username and a passeword, but I found on wiki that when we use the port 25 we don't need the authentification moreover I don't know what's the username  and the password could be ?
Yes the application run on the local network

Comment: putty should return something like: `220 smtp-eu.app.corp (and some version info) ready` the username and password could be your email address and password, if its an exchange, it is probably linked to your domain login and password to login to the corporate network from your PC. Normally this information is obtainable from IT Support.

Comment: Also ask the IT support if port 25 is the port to send email. It might be different or through SSL and for example port 465.

Comment: Thank you, the "putty" works and I have a message like you said 
( 220 wwgrpmrg0001.ad.corp Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready)
the IT support told me that they use the port 25, and they don't use a username or passeword, I don't know what's can I do now,

Comment: Could you try to connect with putty to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` port `25` `telnet` to test is there is a programm on your computer already on port 25?

Comment: Also what u could also try is using gmail as SMTP server with the settings below. This was marked as solution by some ScadaBR User.

1. SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
2. Port: 587
3. Name or email to display as sent from
4. Username = gmail address
5. Password = password from email address
6. Use TLS

Comment: I tried the connection with putty on the localhost and I have an error message "connection refused".
and I have already tried to send email from gmail, I have the same error that I have with (smtp-eu.app.corp) :s